# convert an string to a array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to convert a string to an array in javascript?

```
 var strng = "[a,b]"
```

Expected output:

```
 var arry = ["a","b"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var strng = "[a,b]";
let arr = strng.slice(1,-1).split(",");
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Work for all string like `"[a,b]"` or `"[a,b,c,d]"`

```js
var strng = "[a,b]";
console.log(strng.replace(/\[|]/g, "").split(","));
```